# Adding dictionary values to csv file

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm playing about with working with a dictionary and and adding the contents of it within an existing csv file. This is what I have so far:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
files.Add("test1");
files.Add("test2");

Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
data.Add("Test Column", files.ToList());

foreach ( var columnData in data.Keys)
{
    foreach (var rowData in data[columnData])
    {
        var csv = File.ReadLines(filePath.ToString()).Select((line, index) => index == 0
                ? line + "," + columnData.ToString()
                : line + "," + rowData.ToString()).ToList();
        File.WriteAllLines(filePath.ToString(), csv);
    }
}
```

This sort of works but not the way I'm intending. What I would like the output to be is something along the lines
[image]

but what I'm actually getting is:

[image]

as you'll be able to see I'm getting 2 columns instead of just 1 with a column each for both list values and the values repeating on every single row. How can I fix it so that it's like how I've got in the first image? I know it's something to do with my foreach loop and the way I'm inputting the data into the file but I'm just not sure how to fix it

Edit:

So I have the read, write and AddToCsv methods and when I try it like so:

```
                File.WriteAllLines("file.csv", new string[] { "Col0,Col1,Col2", "0,1,2", "1,2,3", "2,3,4", "3,4,5" });
                var filePath = "file.csv";
                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

                List<string> files = new List<string>() { "test1", "test2" };
                List<string> numbers = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
                Dictionary<string, List<string>> newData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
    {"Test Column", files},
    {"Test2", numbers}
};
                var data1 = ReadCsv(filePath);
                AddToCsv(data1, newData);
                WriteCsv(filePath.ToString(), data1);
```

It works perfectly but when I have the file path as an already created file like so:

```
var filePath = exportFile.ToString();
```

I get the error:

Message :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
Source :System.Private.CoreLib
Stack  :   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) at HMHExtract.Runner.ReadCsv(String path) in C:\tfs\Agility\Client\HMH Extract\HMHExtract\Runner.cs:line 194 at HMHExtract.Runner.Extract(Nullable`1 ct) in C:\tfs\Agility\Client\HMH Extract\HMHExtract\Runner.cs:line 68
Target Site :Void ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException()

The lines in question are:

line 194 -    var col = colNames[i]; of the ReadCsv method
line 68 -     var data1 = ReadCsv(filePath);

Edit:

So after debugging I've figured out where the issue has come from.

In the csv I am trying to update there are 17 columns so obviously 17 rows of values. So the colNames count is 17. csvRecord Count = 0 and i goes up to 16.

However when it reaches a row where in one of the fields there are 2 values separated by a comma, it counts it s 2 row values instead of just 1 so for the row value instead of being string{17} it becomes string{18} and that causes the out of range error.

To clarify, for the row it gets to which causes the error one of the fields has the values Chris Jones, Malcolm Clark. Now instead of counting them as just 1 row, the method counts them as 2 separate ones, how can I change so it doesn't count them as 2 separate rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a way that worked for me, might not be the most efficient but it does work. It involves using csvHelper

```
public static void AppendFile(FileInfo fi, List<string> newColumns, DataTable newRows)
{
    var settings = new CsvConfiguration(new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
    {
        Delimiter = ";"

    };


    var dt = new DataTable();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        using (var dataReader = new CsvDataReader(csv))
        {

            dt.Load(dataReader);

            foreach (var title in newColumns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(title);
            }
            dt.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow row in newRows.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            }
        }

    }

    using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fi.FullName);
    using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, settings);
    // Write columns
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)

    {
        csvWriter.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
    }
    csvWriter.NextRecord();

    // Write row values
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            csvWriter.WriteField(row[i]);
        }
        csvWriter.NextRecord();
    }


}
```

I start by getting the contents of the csv file into a data table and then adding in the new columns that I need. I then clear all the rows in the datatable and add new ones in (the data that is removed is added back in via the newRows parameter) and then write the datatable to the csv file

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to read the csv file first into a list of records, and then add columns to each record. A record is a single row of the csv file, read as a `Dictionary<string, string>`. The keys of this dict are the column names, and the values are the elements of the row in that column.

```
public static void AddToCsv(string path, Dictionary<string, List<string>> newData)
{
        var fLines = File.ReadLines(path);
        var colNames = fLines.First().Split(',').ToList(); // col names in first line
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> rowData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(); // A list of records for all other rows
        foreach (var line in fLines.Skip(1)) // Iterate over second through last lines
        {
            var row = line.Split(',');
            Dictionary<string, string> csvRecord = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            // Add everything from this row to the record dictionary
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                var col = colNames[i];
                csvRecord[col] = row[i];
            }
            rowData.Add(csvRecord);
        }
        
        // Now, add new data
        foreach (var newColName in newData.Keys) 
        {
            var colData = newData[newColName];
            for (int i = 0; i < colData.Count; i++) 
            {
                if (i < rowData.Count) // If the row record already exists, add the new column to it
                    rowData[i].Add(newColName, colData[i]);
                else // Add a row record with only this column
                    rowData.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {newColName, colData[i]} });
            }
            colNames.Add(newColName);
        }
        
        // Now, write all the data
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
        // Write header
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", colNames));
        foreach (var row in rowData) 
        {
            var line = new List<string>();
            foreach (var colName in colNames) // Iterate over columns
            {
                if (row.ContainsKey(colName)) // If the row contains this column, add it to the line
                    line.Add(row[colName]);
                else // Else add an empty string
                    line.Add("");
            }
            // Join all elements in the line with a comma, then write to file
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", line));
        }
        sw.Close();
}
```

To use this, let's create the following CSV file `file.csv`:

```
Col0,Col1,Col2
0,1,2
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

```
List<string> files = new List<string>() {"test1", "test2"};
List<string> numbers = new List<string>() {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
Dictionary<string, List<string>> newData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
    {"Test Column", files},
    {"Test2", numbers}
}

AddToCsv("file.csv", newData);
```

And this results in `file.csv` being modified to:

```
Col0,Col1,Col2,Test Column,Test2
0,1,2,test1,one
1,2,3,test2,two
2,3,4,,three
3,4,5,,four
,,,,five
```

---

To make this more organized, I defined a `struct CsvData` to hold the column names and row records, and a function `ReadCsv()` that reads the file into this struct, and `WriteCsv()` that writes the struct to a file. Then separate responsibilities -- `ReadCsv()` only reads the file, `WriteCsv()` only writes the file, and `AddToCsv()` only adds to the file.

```
public struct CsvData
{
    public List<string> ColNames;
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> RowData;
}

public static CsvData ReadCsv(string path)
{
    List<string> colNames = new List<string>();
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> rowData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(); // A list of records for all other rows
    if (!File.Exists(path)) return new CsvData() {ColNames = colNames, RowData = rowData };
    var fLines = File.ReadLines(path);
    var firstLine = fLines.FirstOrDefault(); // Read the first line
    if (firstLine != null) // Only try to parse the file if the first line actually exists.
    {
        colNames = firstLine.Split(',').ToList(); // col names in first line
        foreach (var line in fLines.Skip(1)) // Iterate over second through last lines
        {
            var row = line.Split(',');
            Dictionary<string, string> csvRecord = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            // Add everything from this row to the record dictionary
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                var col = colNames[i];
                csvRecord[col] = row[i];
            }

            rowData.Add(csvRecord);
        }
    }

    return new CsvData() {ColNames = colNames, RowData = rowData};
}

public static void WriteCsv(string path, CsvData data) 
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
    // Write header
    sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", data.ColNames));
    foreach (var row in data.RrowData) 
    {
        var line = new List<string>();
        foreach (var colName in data.ColNames) // Iterate over columns
        {
            if (row.ContainsKey(colName)) // If the row contains this column, add it to the line
                line.Add(row[colName]);
            else // Else add an empty string
                line.Add("");
        }
        // Join all elements in the line with a comma, then write to file
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", line));
    }
    sw.Close();

}

public static void AddToCsv(CsvData data, Dictionary<string, List<string>> newData)
{
    foreach (var newColName in newData.Keys) 
    {
        var colData = newData[newColName];
        for (int i = 0; i < colData.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (i < data.RowData.Count) // If the row record already exists, add the new column to it
                data.RowData[i].Add(newColName, colData[i]);
            else // Add a row record with only this column
                data.RowData.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {newColName, colData[i]} });
        }
        data.ColNames.Add(newColName);
    }

}
```

Then, to use this, you do:

```
var data = ReadCsv(path);
AddToCsv(data, newData);
WriteCsv(path, data);
```

Comment: Incredibly detailed answer, thank you for that! However when I try do this, I am getting the error:  Message :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index') when calling the ReadCsv method, do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: it seems to get to this line:   rowData.Add(csvRecord); and that's where the error occurs

Comment: @lross15 That's weird, since adding an element to a list shouldn't cause an IndexError. It works fine for me, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/69WorA Can you create a fiddle with the code you're trying and have it reproduce the error?

Comment: I've edited the question to show what I've done. It seems to work great if you create the csv first and use that one like you've done in the fiddle but if it's with an already created csv, that's where I get the error for some reason and not sure what exactly is causing it

Comment: @lross15 I see now. The error was because it was trying to read the file and that file didn't exist. I modified `ReadCsv()` to check if the file exists and return an empty struct. See the updated code.

Comment: Hi, I tried it with the updated code but unfortunately I'm still getting that out of range error

Comment: Hi again, I figured out why I'm getting the error, but not sure the best way to fix this, I've updated my question to explain what it is going on